# How to debug code 1 in gcp cloud shell on Kubeflow deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy kubeflow. I had previously done it once from CLI using the default resource settings. This time I am doing kfctl build and kfctl apply in two separate steps so that I can control resources needed for kubeflow. Now when I call kfctl apply the gcloud shell exits with code 1. Also tried the same from the shell in my local machine after I had authenticated with gcloud auth application-default login and gcloud auth login. Same result. Any pointers on how I should debug.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what the error is here without taking a look at your code and output error.
I suggest you to take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/customizing-gke/) from the official kubeflow site to customize your builds.